# Html page onload, show video on a javascript blockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an HTML page. I want to show a video on a javascript block UI anytime when a user lands on that page. Any help on it? Thanks.

Comment: Kind of depends. You can use a cookie or if they have to login or something you can save it to the database.

Comment: @Matt: thnaks man. more interested in the video pop up on the blockUI

Comment: not sure what you mean then. check out http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home) code and then..

Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      // show modal window that has content of #popcontent div in its body
      $.fancybox(
         $('#popcontent").html(),
         {
            'autoDimensions': true,
            'modal': true
         }
      );
    })
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Some example page content</h1>        
    <div id="popcontent" style="display:none;">
      <video src="yourlinktovideo.ogg" width="640" height="480"></video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Popoup with a video player will be opened as soon as the DOM is ready (and the documentready event of jQuery if fired). In my example it is a modal window so user won't be able to close it to return to content of the page which is underneath.