# HTML5-Bug in Safari? Video doesn't work when using local files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html5-video

I try to build a local JS-based mediathek with HTML5 video. the code is the same like in this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/eninox/3), where it is working well for online content. but when I use this code with local files (like you could [find here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896178/VideoLoadError.zip)) Safari throws the error

> INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an
>   object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

after starting the video the third time by klicking on the thumb image, which opens the player and loads the video URL.

the error comes from '$vplayer.currentTime = 0.0;' without this line the problem stays, but no error is thrown at all.

I know this error means that the video is not loaded and it is caused by - but why did it load the first two times before?

edit: I also tried different approaches with absolute paths from 'file://' to 'file:///' - nothing changes.

**edit: I found out that this behaviour is gone when using the browser engine of a objective-c WebView component (iOS). also it works when using chrome. so it seems to be a bug of safari?**

the code used:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />    
</head>
<body>

  <div data-role="page" id="gamepad">
    <div id="videolink">
    </div>
            <div data-role="popup" id="vplayerpopup" data-position-to="window" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" class="ui-content" data-tolerance="5,5,5,5" data-transition="fade">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
            <video id="vplayer" width="640" height="360" controls> 
                <source id="vsource" src="" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and

```
var $videoblock =   '<div class="ui-block-a videoblock">'
    +                   '   <div class="videoPreviewImageWrapper">'
      +                 '       <a href="#vplayerpopup" data-rel="popup" onclick="mediathekVideolink = \'http://blog.gingertech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/LCA_MM_AVProc2011/HelloWorld.mp4\';">'
        +                   '           <div class="videolink">'
          +                 '               <img src="http://leanbackplayer.com/videos/poster/sintel_640x360.jpg" width="218" height="164" alt="Movie Title">'
            +                   '               <div class="mediathek_film_titel">Movie Title</div>'
              +                 '               <div class="mediathek_film_dauer">03:56</div>'
                +                   '               <div class="mediathek_film_text">Some Text about the video</div>'
                  +                 '           </div>'
                    +                   '       </a>'
                      +                 '   </div>'
                        +                   '</div>';

$('#videolink').append($videoblock);

var mediathekVideolink = 'none';
var mediaplayerIsPlaying = false;

$( '#gamepad' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow', function(){

    $( "#vplayerpopup" ).on({
            popupbeforeposition: function(opt1, opt2) { //console.log('mediathekVideolink: ' + mediathekVideolink);
                //console.log('popupbeforeposition');
                $('#vsource').attr('src', mediathekVideolink); 
                var $vplayer = $('#vplayer').get(0); 
                if(!mediaplayerIsPlaying) {
                    $vplayer.load();
                    $vplayer.play();
                    mediaplayerIsPlaying = true;
                }
            },
            popupafterclose: function() {
                //console.log('popupafterclose');
                mediaplayerIsPlaying = false;
                var $vplayer = $('#vplayer').get(0); //console.log('currentTime: ' + $vplayer.currentTime); console.log('currentSrc: ' + $vplayer.currentSrc);
                $vplayer.pause();
                $vplayer.currentTime = 0.0;
            }
        });
});

$( '#gamepad' ).live( 'pagehide', function(){
    $( "#vplayerpopup" ).off();

});
```

Comment: thats because I ask questions that are hard to answer. ;-)
I do what I can, man... and one simple value is not what I call analytics. at least I made an working example!

Comment: O.k - I went over my open questions. many of them I answered myself and nerver accepted them. am I better now? :-) [for the hostory: changes rate from 62% to 92%]

Comment: I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8mtWH/2/) to try and understand it better. I am guessing `var $videoblock` is example content that would be returned when selecting a movie? How are we to replicate or troubleshoot the issue if it only happens when using your local files?

Comment: ok, you are right - here comes a 'not-working' example setup: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896178/VideoLoadError.zip. var $videoblock simulates the dynamic creation of a longer video-list out of ajax loaded content.

Comment: it may work when using the FILE object from HTML5, but I caan't find out how to generate a file out of 'mediathekVideolink'...

Comment: by the way: $vplayer.currentTime is not the reason why the video doesn't load the third time it is called. if you delete this, it doesn't work without any error thrown.

Comment: @Twisty: could you reproduce the described behaviour with my example files using local video?

Comment: @Titanium: I added a sample file so you don't have to read too much.
thnx!

Comment: I downloaded your Zip and tested it locally. As you mentioned it does not seem to be working. It's not very clear to me what you want it to accomplish, this might be cause I am just using test data.

Comment: The jQuery `live` function is depreciated as of version 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Personally, I would replace `live("pagebeforeshow", function() {` with `$(document).on('pageinit', function() {` but I don't know what your exact intentions are with this code.

Comment: @Titanium: No, that changes nothing, Still not working.

Comment: I found out that this behaviour is gone when using the browser engine of a objective-c WebView component. so it seems to be a bug of safari?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "local"? You mean filesystem paths?

Comment: Is the page you're calling this from also on the filesystem, and are the videos in the same folder or in a folder directly beneath?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes. and it works fine using chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now managed to work around this by refreshing the page every time I close the videoplayers popup using

```
function stopVideo(n){
    mediaplayerIsPlaying = false;
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[n];
    video.pause();
    location.reload();
}
```

this is only the worst case workaround solution - but at least I can deliver this as 'kind of working'...

Comment: another workaround you could try is putting it in a fancybox like this person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174573/html-page-onload-show-video-on-a-javascript-blockui

Comment: and you can put that video on another page and then have the page load in the fancybox popup each time. This way, the video is always reloaded. Should work fine with online or offline file systems.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, a lot of browsers don't like working with local files. Firefox does not have this specific problem, but it has other ones (related to CSS/WOFF fonts).

The solution I use is to have a local development web server (like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)), and then using various web browsers to test. You should be able to setup firewall options to only allow the Apache server on your computer, and not out on your local network.

Plus, you get PHP/Perl/etc. and other scripting languages you don't get on just local files.

Comment: Not even on your local computer like this? You can block it from responding to non-local requests...